# check if username exists on form submit

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This is my code.

**.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#username").focusout(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:site_url()+'/client/checkUserName',
            data:{'username':$("#username").val()},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(result){
                if(result != 'false'){
                  $('#message').text('Username exists');  
                }

            }
        });  
    });
```

**.html**

```
<form id='form1'  method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
        <span id="message" style="color:red"></span>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="regis" class="btn"/>
</form>
```

Its working fine on focusout.
How to make the form to not submit if username exists?

Suppose there is a hidden field in the form say

```
   <input type="text" hidden id="type" value="<?php echo $type;?>">
```

Then if value exists in the hidden field then the username neednot be checked if already exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply disable submit button

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#username").focusout(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:site_url()+'/client/checkUserName',
        data:{'username':$("#username").val()},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(result){
            if(result != 'false'){
              $('#message').text('Username exists');
              $('#regis').attr('disabled','disabled');
            } else {
              $('#regis').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you guarantee that the asynchronous ajax response will be processed before any intervening events, such as form submission?

Comment: we can disable it by default on page load. but of course we need additional server checks on submission.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. A user could enter some unlikely username (ie. junk). On focusout the script would check the name and ratify it, removing the disable on submit. The user could then edit the name and immediately press submit. It might be possible to get something like that working, but there are so many edge cases that it seems very fragile.

Comment: is there a way by which this function only takes place if another field value is null

Comment: Kevin, as i noted above, there is no need to do it on clientside. This is only some type of more userfriendly check. Developer, to make it work if another field is null - you need only one additional IF.

Answer (score 0):

If you only check that the username exists in javascript, your site won't be secure.  A hacker doesn't need to actually click the button or execute your client-side code to get a submit to take place.

So that means you need to check for username existance on the server-side when the submit has already happened.  With that being the case, there isn't much to gain from the javascript check.

You also don't want to provide hackers with a way to check which usernames exist and which do not.  If you check after submit, a hacker doesn't know if the username was invalid, or if the password was wrong.

EDIT: So far @КонстантинРекунов has offered the only javascript that might work.  However, see my comments under his answer regarding the fragile nature of the solution.  Any solution like this will be inherently fragile.

The only reasonable reason for doing something like this is to suggest alternatives during a signup process.  Even then in is bad practice.  I recommend you alter your intended design.

Comment: Isn't sending an AJAX request to the PHP script checking on the server-side?

Comment: yeah, i understand that but i need to check if username exists without page submit.

Comment: @sbeliv01 It has to do with where the check action happens. A server-side action of refusing login is different from a client-side action of refusing login.  The check itself is only half of the intended action.

Comment: @Developer Can you explain why it is mandatory that you check for username existence before submit? (I expect it isn't possible.)

Comment: Am I missing something here? How is using AJAX to find out whether the username exists any different than submitting the form and getting the same results? AJAX *is* checking server-side and returning the message client-side without having to submit the form. There's no difference between the two except one method doesn't reload the page to get the results.

Comment: @sbeliv01 Yes the decision about the name would be server-side, but the decision about what that means world be client-side. An interface for attackers to easily determine which usernames are used or available is an attack vector.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to put your js code in a function and add: `return false;` to the if the check fails then add `onsubmit = "[functionName]";`.

Answer (score 0):

you should add return false like and also where you call the function

```
 if(result != 'false'){
                  $('#message').text('Username exists'); 
                   return true; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      return false;
                    }
```